# Data not being passed between activities through Intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

```
//In MainActivity
binding.doneButton.setOnClickListener {
            checkValid()
            if (valid){
                val bmi: Double = calculateBmi().round(1)
                val bmr: Double = calculateBmr().round(2)
                Intent(this, DailyActivity::class.java).also{
                    intent.putExtra("EXTRA_BMI", bmi)
                    intent.putExtra("EXTRA_BMR", bmr)
                    startActivity(it)
                }

            }
        }
//In DailyActivity
var bmi = intent.getDoubleExtra("EXTRA_BMI", 0.0)
var bmr = intent.getDoubleExtra("EXTRA_BMR", 0.0)
```

I want to pass these two Double values bmi and bmr from my MainActivity to DailyActivity. I checked the values and they work fine inside MainActivity. But when I try to pass them to DailyActivity, the default value of 0.0 is being used. I tried intent?.extras?.getDouble("EXTRA_BMI") as well but that's not working either. How can I fix this?

(Btw round is an extension function I found on SO. It works fine. That's not why the code isn't working)

Comment: Hello, have you tried another this: `(intent.extras?.get("EXTRA_BMI") as? Double) ?: 0.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your `also` block, by calling `intent.putExtra(...)` you are altering the current Activity's intent (the one you would access with `this@MainActivity.intent`), not the one you just created.

What you want is

```
Intent(this, DailyActivity::class.java).also{
    it.putExtra("EXTRA_BMI", bmi)
    it.putExtra("EXTRA_BMR", bmr)
    startActivity(it)
}
```